# Whitelabel Error Page error (Spring Boot + React)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

`localhost:9000` is opening fine on the browser. And if I navigate to a link from the menu like `localhost:9000/about`, it is working fine.

But if I hit `localhost:9000/about` directly without going to `localhost:9000` then nothing happens on the local and if I do the same on server, following error is produced:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Feb 12 14:09:05 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because in your application you have not defined what your application should do when it will get url request localhost:9000. 
For every Request mapping you need to define the operation you want to perform. In your case for localhost:9000 you have to write what you want to do as you have done for local:9000/about.

```
@RequestMapping("")
@ResponseBody
Function_For_HandlingRequest{}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hit `http://localhost:9090/about` directly, SpringBoot redirect To a `/login.html`.
So, Redirect every page to `index.html` .

https://github.com/geowarin/boot-react/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/react/config/SinglePageAppConfig.java

The WebMvcConfigurer interface, starting with Spring 5, contains default implementations for all its methods. As a result, the abstract adapter (WebMvcConfigurerAdapter) class was marked as deprecated.

```
package your.package.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolverChain;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Redirects every page to index.html
 * Used to handle the router
 */
@Configuration
public class SinglePageAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
      .resourceChain(false)
      .addResolver(new PushStateResourceResolver());
  }

  private class PushStateResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {
    private Resource index = new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
    private List<String> handledExtensions = Arrays.asList("html", "js", "json", "csv", "css", "png", "svg", "eot", "ttf", "woff", "appcache", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "ico");
    private List<String> ignoredPaths = Arrays.asList("api");

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
      return resolve(requestPath, locations);
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
      Resource resolvedResource = resolve(resourcePath, locations);
      if (resolvedResource == null) {
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return resolvedResource.getURL().toString();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return resolvedResource.getFilename();
      }
    }

    private Resource resolve(String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations) {
      if (isIgnored(requestPath)) {
        return null;
      }
      if (isHandled(requestPath)) {
        return locations.stream()
          .map(loc -> createRelative(loc, requestPath))
          .filter(resource -> resource != null && resource.exists())
          .findFirst()
          .orElseGet(null);
      }
      return index;
    }

    private Resource createRelative(Resource resource, String relativePath) {
      try {
        return resource.createRelative(relativePath);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    private boolean isIgnored(String path) {
      return ignoredPaths.contains(path);
    }

    private boolean isHandled(String path) {
      String extension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(path);
      return handledExtensions.stream().anyMatch(ext -> ext.equals(extension));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in Application

```
 @Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> {
        ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html");
        factory.addErrorPages(error404Page);
    };
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP6qW.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems to work either way